# sql как сформировать запрос на поиск маршрута в таблице минуя параметр id в строке cities/{id}

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, psql

дано :
таблица

```
{
routes:[
{
id:1,
path:'/cities/{id}'},
{
id:2,
path:'/cities/}
]

}
```

входная строка:

/cities/1312test

Как делать выборку если нужно найти /cities/{id}, опираясь на исходную строку  /cities/1312test

**такое условие выборки (where path ilike '%/cities/1312test/%)  проигнорирует строку с параметром, как сформировать запрос для строки с {id} ?'**

Comment: а что такое "опираясь на исходную строку", что из входной строки должно искаться ? И почему в начале приведен какой то сложный json, не похожий на обычную прямоугольную таблицу реляционной БД (я про странную вложенность routes->записи)

Comment: т.е задача не понятна?

Comment: нет, не понятна. вы сами написали как ее решать, на мой взгляд, указав `like '%/vities/%'`

Comment: не проще ли этот вопрос решить на стороне ЯП, а не БД? Потому что может быть ситуация, когда есть URL **/cities/check** и **/cities/1312test**, и вот эту ситуацию разрулить запросом будет ой как сложно

Comment: в плоскости одного сервиса действительно проще, однако мне нужно сделать прокси сервис где проверяется разрешен ли доступ у текущего пользователя к такому то маршруту.
и будет 3 сущности бекенда с различными ролями. т.е из нодного бекенд сервиса буду управлять 3 другими сервисами для проксирования запроса